Can I inject other thread into Spring boot ThreadPool
I am working on a JPOS project using Q2's ISORequestListener. When I received an ISOMsg, I want to start a backend service thread. But the backend service always return null and spring beans can not be autowired within ISORequestlistner (I am following this).
Is there anyway I can inject backend service to ThreadPool at the beginning of Spring Boot?
This is my current listener:
@Component
    public class ISO8583Listener implements ISORequestListener {
    @Autowired
    private BackendServ backendServ ;


    public ISO8583Listener() {
            AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bpp = new 
                        AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
            WebApplicationContext currentContext = 
                        WebApplicationContextLocator.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
            bpp.setBeanFactory(currentContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
            bpp.processInjection(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process (ISOSource source, ISOMsg m) {
        try {
            if ("200".equals (m.getMTI())) {
                //some backend service process here

                //end

                m.setResponseMTI();
                source.send(m);
            } 
        } catch (ISOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

And my configuration:
    @Configuration
    public class WebApplicationContextLocator implements ServletContextInitializer {
        private static WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

        public static WebApplicationContext getCurrentWebApplicationContext() {
            return webApplicationContext;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
          webApplicationContext = 
                WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        }
    }


A thread pooll usually decides when and how many threads to spawn. I'd be surprised if you can inject threads from outside.

What do you mean by "inject backend service to ThreadPool"?

Also, can you please share the Spring Boot version you are trying?

Can you also share how you are configuring your beans and starting the application?

I think this doesn't work because Spring class loader and Q2 class loader are different. So, when you try to access the web application context from within the ISO request listener instance that is created by Q2 (Which is a different instance from the component created by Spring), in that classloader the static variable webApplicationContextis null. You would need to get a reference to the BackendServ instance created by Spring in some other way.

@AndrésAlcarraz Yes, You got me. I want to inject backend service to ThreadPool

And I wonder is there anyway I can make BackendServ created by Spring.
I am using spring boot 2.6.

@MiSFhE, again, what do you mean by " I want to inject backend service to ThreadPool"?

@AndrésAlcarraz thank you for your supporting. I realize that my BackendServ use some servlet to process record logs and that costs the listener when call BackendServ can not get the ApplicationContext.

Did you take a look at the jPOS' TransactionManager. I believe it solves the problem you're trying to solve.

One way to achieve what you are trying to do, is by registering the backendServ in the NameRegistrar and then get it in the request listener constructor. It wouldn´t be a component since it is created by the jPOS framework not the Spring framework:
package com.example.jpos_demo;

import org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg;
import org.jpos.iso.ISORequestListener;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOSource;
import org.jpos.util.NameRegistrar;

public class DemoRequestListener implements ISORequestListener {
    BackendServ serv;

    public DemoRequestListener() throws NameRegistrar.NotFoundException {
        serv = NameRegistrar.get("serv", 1000L); /
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean process(ISOSource isoSource, ISOMsg isoMsg) {
        try {
            if ("200".equals (m.getMTI())) {
                //some backend service process here

                //end

                m.setResponseMTI();
                source.send(m);
            } 
        } catch (ISOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}

To register the BackendServ in NameRegistrar just write the following code next to where you instantiate your bean:
NameRegistrar.register("serv", backendServ);

One last word, this won't work, and I don't know a workaround, for spring-dev-tools, this is because of the way spring-dev-tools handles the classloader for the hot reload.
